# Class is not a template error when converting code from non-template to templates

Tags: c++, templates

I'm getting an error from the *inline* line, which says that 'DListCursor is not a template' (It is in its own .hpp file), and 'template argument list must match the parameter list', which I don't understand how it isn't doing that.

DListNode.hpp

```
template <typename ItemType>

class DListNode {
    template <typename> friend class DListCursor;

public:
    DListNode(ItemType item, std::shared_ptr<DListNode> prev = nullptr, std::shared_ptr<DListNode> next = nullptr);

#ifdef DEBUG
    // ~DListNode() { std::cerr << "DListNode " << _item << std::endl; }
#endif

private:
    ItemType _item;
    std::shared_ptr<DListNode> _next;
    std::weak_ptr<DListNode> _prev;
};

template <typename ItemType>
inline DListNode<DListCursor<ItemType>>::DListNode(ItemType item, std::shared_ptr<DListNode<ItemType>> prev, std::shared_ptr<DListNode<ItemType>> next) {
    _item = item;
    _prev = prev;
    _next = next;
}
```

DListCursor.hpp - I removed 95% of the public functions since I don't think they're relevant.

```
template <typename ItemType>
class DListCursor {

public:
    // constructor
    DListCursor();

private:
    void _copy(const DListCursor &source);
    std::shared_ptr<DListNode> _find(size_t position) const;
    std::shared_ptr<DListNode> _head, _cursor, _tail;
};
```

Comment: We'll need to see DListCursor's header (possibly trimmed down a bit) as well.

Comment: @MarkStorer Hopefully that should be enough.

Comment: Which file includes which and where do you forward declare stuff?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot DListCursor.hpp has all of the functions for dealing with the cursor list, but DListNode.hpp has the declarations for each individual node in the cursor list.

Answer (score 2):

Forward declaring classes is a bit different than forward declaring a template class.

When you type:

```
class ClassA;
```

Or even:

```
struct ClassB;
```

This tells the compiler that a type exists and will be implemented.

Notice that as soon as you do that, you can use the type:

```
void stuff(ClassA& parameter_of_declared_class);
```

And the compiler expect a definition that look like this:

```
class ClassA { /* ... */ };
```

If `ClassA` was in reality a template, the function declaration syntax would not be valid as it misses template parameters. Any syntax that uses the incomplete type would become retroactively invalid. That would be really bad.

This is why the compiler has to know in advance if you intend to declare a template type or a simple type. They are different kind of entity and should be declared differently.

A template class is forwarded declared like this:

```
template<typename> class ClassA;
```

Notice that it looks a lot like your friend declaration.

If you have defaulted template parameter, they must be in the declaration too:

```
template<typename, typename = int> class ClassA;
```

Comment: forward declaration is not required here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/EZGe8DDySxceg1YK. Friend declaration with "elaborated class specifier" doesn't require previous declaration: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend (3)